# AutoFixture deep freeze of object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture, automoq

I have a class

```
public class GetDashboardStatisticsResult
{
  public GetPublicationStatisticsResult Publications { get; set; }
  public GetSwitchboardStatisticsResult Switchboard { get; set; }
}
```

Which I use in my test like this

```
public async Task Should_return_correct_statistics([Frozen] GetDashboardStatisticsResult expectedResult);
```

And I wonder if there is there a way to freeze `GetDashboardStatisticsResult` together with its properties?

So at the end we have three types frozen - `GetDashboardStatisticsResult`, `GetPublicationStatisticsResult` and `GetSwitchboardStatisticsResult`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think AutoFixture has any feature that enables something like that, but you could, possibly, work around it like this:

```
[Theory, AutoData]
public async Task Should_return_correct_statistics(
    [Frozen]GetPublicationStatisticsResult dummy1,
    [Frozen]GetSwitchboardStatisticsResult dummy2,
    [Frozen]GetDashboardStatisticsResult expectedResult)
{
    // Test goes here...
}
```

The best solution is probably to reconsider the design of the types in question. I've never encountered needing such a feature. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have a handler `GetDashboardStatistics` which just aggregates other handlers - `IGetPublicationStatistics`, `IGetSwitchboardStatistics`, `IGetAutomationStatistics`, etc. 
So I've written a test for `GetDashboardStatistics` like this https://pastebin.com/zB5ZVXcC and wonder if I can get rid of `fixture.Freeze` inside the test

Comment: The solution with dummy parameters works well, but I don't like warnings about unused params :)